# Word suggestion

Tags: single-word-requests

In the case of writing an engineering work instruction, is there a single verb describing the action of removing a part, such as an o-ring, from its installed position, and reinstall the part to its intended position for the purpose of removing any undesirable condition of the original installation.

Comment: "reseat"  ------